# Java Casting trouble while printing

Tags: java, casting

Noob Question.

```
double answer = 13/5;
System.out.println(answer);
```

Why does that return 2 instead of 2.6.

As in must i say 
     (double) 13/5 
everytime i want to print a double.

Comment: It's got nothing to do with printing. The problem is that you're performing integer division - both of the operands of `13/5` are integers. The integer result is then being promoted to a `double`. I'll see if I can find a duplicate - this has come up several times.

Comment: Q: must i say (double) 13/5 everytime i want to print a double?  A: Yes.  Or, better, `double answer = 13.0/5.0;`.  You *MUST* have a double operand in your expression to evaluate a double result.

Comment: In addition to the answers already posted, you could also do this:  `double answer = 13d/5d;`

Comment: `double answer 13.0 / 5.0` would solve your problem. If you want to verify that `System.out.println` is not the problem, read that: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28float%29

Answer (score 0):

you must tell java that you want a double division:

```
double answer = 13/5.0; // or 13 / (double) 5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

13 and 5 are integers. That means that you divide them as integers. As a result, you will get an integer. So what you have to do is to cast them as double  like that:

```
double answer = 13 / (double) 5;
```

Or write them like that:

```
double answer = 13 / 5.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `13` and `5` are integers, so the result will be an integer that you are assigning to a `double` variable

You need to specify your numbers should be considered as `double`

Answer (score 0):

The division takes place between two `int`s and the result is also an `int` which is finally cast into a `double`. You should declare the operands as `double`s to get the desired result.